# Data not get inserted in Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, ms-access

I am developing a C# Windows application. I have used access database. When I selecting data from database I am getting data, but when inserting data it's not gets inserted and also it's not showing any error.

But when I run the same insert query in Access it gets inserted. Here is my code:

```
    public void connCheck()
    {
        try
        {
            cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\MyDatabase.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=2013");
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cn.Open();                
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }
    }

    public bool ExecuteNonQuery()
    {
        try
        {
            connCheck();
            string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tblResult(ExamSet,SetId,FullMarks,ObtainedMarks,MarksPercentage,ElapsedTime,LastQIndex,CreatedDate,Completed)
            Values(1,27,'200.00',0,0,0,1,DATE(),'N')";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;                
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch(OleDbException ex)
        {
            ErrorMsg = ex.ToString();
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might help if you post the content of sqlQuery

Comment: i have added my query in code please check.

Comment: Give break point and check in which place you are lacking...

Comment: i have tried that also, but not getting any error and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: This is just a wild guess when you open up your MDB do you happen to see a `Security Warning Certain contents in the database has been disabled`  ?

Comment: Yes i getting this. May be this is the problem, then what is the solution.

Comment: @Raghubar It would be helpful for other's if you could post your solution

Comment: Kyle.. Actually there is no problem in my code. Problem is that i have created database file in a folder. But when i build the project it created a duplicate database with same folder an file name in bin folder. So every time its gets inserted in that database And i was checking in the database file which i have created. So i think its not working.

Answer (score 3):

You did not defined your cmd..
add this line

```
    OledbCommand cmd=new OledbCommand();
```

Comment: I have tried it not working...

Comment: I think there is something wrong in access security..

Answer (score 2):

How about replacing your query code like this

```
 string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tblResult([ExamSet],[SetId],[FullMarks],[ObtainedMarks],[MarksPercentage],[ElapsedTime],[LastQIndex],[CreatedDate],[Completed])
        Values(1,27,'200.00',0,0,0,1,DATE(),'N')";
```

**Update:**

One of the issues could be `Security warning` that disables the content.

Try and see if this works (Go to your MDB):

1. Click on 'External Data' tab
2. There should be a Security Warning that states "Certain content in the database has been disabled"
3. Click the 'Options' button
4. Select 'Enable this content' and click the OK button

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But its not working.

Comment: I have tried it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try parameterised queries via cmd.Parameters.Add or AddRange. Example

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_name (a, b, c) VALUES (@a, @b, @c)");
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { new SqlParameter("@a", field1), new SqlParameter("@b", field2), new SqlParameter("@c", field2) });
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks everyone for your help, I got the solution. Actually there is no problem in my code. Problem is that I have created database file in a folder. But when I build the project it created a duplicate database with same folder an file name in bin folder.

So every time it gets inserted in that database. And I was checking in the database file which I have created. So I thought it's not working.